# Helping hand for Cocos2D. How to start from very beginning?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios-simulator, cocos2d-iphone

I am a newbie with Cocos2D.I know xcode & objective C.what else I need to learn for Cocos2D.

I want to learn Cocos2D.Is there any good materials like free online books or examples for Cococs2D?

Since I google alot but not able to get unto mark with the material.Can anybody be helping hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this page and the following :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for your time,but I have checked it earlier.But is there any online free books available just like iPhone iOS Beginner, iPhoneSDKApplicationDevelopment.I want to learn it in details since I am very new to this.

Answer (score 1):

There is great book to begin "Learn iPhone and iPad Cocos2D Game Development"

Comment: I didn't find any link to download this file.Can you provide me the free download url for this book..

Comment: I believe the book being recommended is a commercial release.

Answer (score 1):

You should start with the official site's list of third party tutorials:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/resources:iphone_recommended_reading